# How to query TRC20 transaction records in Python?

Tags: python, tron

```
def test3(address):
  url = 'https://apilist.tronscan.org/api/transfer?'
  payload = {
    "sort": 'timestamp',
    'count':True,
    'limit':20,
    'start':0,
    'token':'_',
    'address':address
  }
  res = requests.get(url, params=payload)
  obj = json.loads(res.text)
  print(res)

test3('TQAuZ2YsGgPRPNpHXxoJZLHsvuxrLrnVEM')
```

I am trying to query the transfer record of TRC20 of an address. According to the API, I only found the record of TRX.  But I need to check the USDT transfer record of TRC20
How should I modify it?

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to help

```
def test3(address):
  url = f'https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/{address}/transactions/trc20?'
  payload = {
    "sort": 'blockNumber',
    'limit':10,
  }
  res = requests.get(url,params=payload)
  obj = json.loads(res.text)
  return obj
```